# get a process's private environment variables in Windows using powershell

Tags: windows-10, powershell, process, environment-variables

I have a process (testxx) running on my Database. Every time a user connects with the database the process will start separate session for. All processes include a private environment variable(Client-Nr) with different values.
I want to invoke a particular process with the particular private environment variable. I used the following command:

> Let's say there are 5x "testxx"-processes. I want to invoke the one process which has the value "Client-Two" in the private environment variable "Client-Nr".

Therefore, I use the following code:

```
get-process -name "testxx" | where-object {$env:Client-Nr -eq "client-Two"}
```

It didn't invoke the process I needed. I checked with the following command, if PowerShell recognize the private environment variable:

```
(get-process -Name "testxx").StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables
```

PowerShell didn't recognized this private environment variable. However, if I open "Process Hacker", choose the specific "testxx" process, I see the private environment variable "client-Nr" with that particular "Client-nr" value. How can I invoke this kind of private environment variable via PowerShell?

Answer (score 1):

This is much more complicated than you'd think, because this information
is only found in the kernel. The nicely documented `GetEnvironmentStrings`
only works for the calling process.

If you want to go cross-process, you have to write a program that
uses the
[NtQueryInformationProcess function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntqueryinformationprocess)
and
[ReadProcessMemory function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-readprocessmemory)
to search for this data inside the process memory.

You can find some of the required code in the CodeProject demo program of
[Get Process Info with NtQueryInformationProcess](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19685/Get-Process-Info-with-NtQueryInformationProcess).

As an alternative, you create a DLL and do
[DLL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_injection)
to inject it into the processes memory space.

As I said, this is complicated.

Comment: It would be simpler for all processes to record themselves on a text file with their PID and Client-Nr, that you could use for the selection.

Comment: Isn't there any option, doing this with powershell ?

Comment: You can call `NtQueryInformationProcess` and `ReadProcessMemory` from PowerShell. See [an example](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PowerSploit/1.0.0.0/Content/ReverseEngineering%5CGet-PEB.ps1).

Answer (score 0):

This is messy but not complicated using Python [`psutil.Process.environ()` library function](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=environ#psutil.Process.environ).

In one terminal

```
$ $ENV:test = 'abc'
$ $PID
108444
```

In another:

```
$ python -c 'import psutil; print(psutil.Process(pid=108444).environ()["TEST"])'
abc
```

(Notice the variable names are capitalized in Windows.)

---

The documentation says:

> Note: this might not reflect changes made after the process started.

but it appears to update in real time on Windows 10.